# Date Picker Skip a disabled day Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to skip disabled dates.

**working:** The code can skip the dates that are from the array:

```
var disabledDates = ["2020-08-07","2020-08-06"] <br />
```

**not working**: The code wont skip the disabled days:

```
var day = day.getDay();
var monday = 1;
```

**Working jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9Lfjdh54/4/

```js
var disabledDates = ["2020-08-07", "2020-08-06"]

$("#picker").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(day) {

    const string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', day);
    var day = day.getDay();
    var monday = 1;

    if (day != monday) {
      return [true] && [disabledDates.indexOf(string) == -1]
    } else {
      return [false]
    }
  }
});

$('.next-day').on("click", function() {
  var date = $('#picker').datepicker('getDate');
  do {
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
  }
  while (disabledDates.indexOf(string) >= 0);
  $('#picker').datepicker("setDate", date);
});

$('#picker').datepicker();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="picker"></div>

<br/><br/>

<button class="next-day">Next</button>
```

Comment: the issue is that the days under monday is not skipped but the days stated in the array is skippef i want to skip all the disabled dates

Comment: have you seen my **jsfiddle** ? try to press next it doesn't skip the days under monday where as the 3 disabled dates are skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the days under Monday are not skipped

More specifically, these are not skipped *when clicking the next day button*.

As the next button isn't using the datepicker to determine which dates are available, the same logic used to disable the dates needs to be reused in the next button.

In simplest terms, this means adding the Monday check:

```
   var day = date.getDay();
   var monday = 1;
 }
 while (disabledDates.indexOf(string) >= 0 || day==monday);
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xjq63mv2/

```js
var disabledDates = ["2020-08-07", "2020-08-06"]

$("#picker").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(day) {

    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', day);
    var day = day.getDay();
    var monday = 1;

    if (day != monday) {
      return [true] && [disabledDates.indexOf(string) == -1]
    } else {
      return [false]
    }
  }
});



$('.next-day').on("click", function() {
  var date = $('#picker').datepicker('getDate');
  do {
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    var day = date.getDay();
    var monday = 1;
  }
  while (disabledDates.indexOf(string) >= 0 || day == monday);
  $('#picker').datepicker("setDate", date);
});
$('#picker').datepicker();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="picker"></div>

<br/><br/>

<button class="next-day">Next</button>
<button class="prev-day">Previous</button>
```